# loop through to empty an array list till condition met

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to park all the vehicles in this arraylist `vehicles` in to a garage space till no more vehicle left to be in the array List.
Once the for loop ends, it will be holding remaining  objects in the `vehicles` arraylist since some conditions are not met like mentioned in the code. I used a while loop to keep on running till list empty out.  Once each for-loop ends, I want to remove the car that was parked and also, I want to change the position of the garage space in order to park the remaining  vehicles in the vehicles arraylist.

this is what I tried, but it is not adding any more objects to the garage on the next for loop starts.

```
while (vehicles.size() != 0) { // this checks if any vehicles are not 0
        for (int i = vehicles.size() - 1; i >= 0;) { // decrementing the arraylist
            for (int j = 0; j < garage.size() && i >= 0;) { // incrementing the arraylist of garage
                    if (this.garage.get(j).getSpace() == this.vehicles.get(i).getSpace()) { //if the garage space matches vehicles space
                        if (this.garage.get(j).garageRequest(vehicles.get(i).getvehiclesType()) //if the vehicle type matches garage type 
                                && this.garage.get(j).getLimit() > 0) { //and if that particular garage space have no more space left to park the car.
                            this.garage.get(j).addvehicles(vehicles.get(i)); // we park the car into the space. the parked car can be accessed by  this.garage.get(j).
                            this.vehicles.remove(i); // we remove the car from the arraylist
                            i--; //decrementing the size of the list.
                            break; // break the loop
                        } else {
                            j++; // if there is no space left or vehicle type doesn't matches we incrementing the garage size to get the next available garage
                        }
                    } else {
                        i--; // if vehicle and garage is not on the same space.
                    }

            }

        } // end of the vehicles arraylist looping.
        
        /*
        
        I have around morethan 90 more cars to be parked after this loop ends since some conditions are not met.
        So, I'm looping till all the vehicles arraylist is empty. 
        
        Once this for loop ends, i want to remove the car that was parked
        and Also, I want to change the position of the garage space to hold the next vehicles
            
        */
        
        for(int i = 0; i< garage.size();i++) { // looping the available garage size
            if(this.garage.get(i).getCarry().size() != 0) { // if garage at an index holding a vehicle in its space
                for (int j=0; j < this.garage.get(i).getCarry().size(); j++) { // looping the garage at index by its space
                    this.garage.get(i).setCurrentSpace(this.garage.get(i).getCarry().get(j).getDestinationSpace()); // changing the space of the garage to hold the next 90 vehicles.
                    if (this.garage.get(i).removeVehicles(this.garage.get(i).getCarry().get(j)));// removes the vehicle from garage space
                }
            }
        }
        
        
    
        

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```java
while (vehicles.size() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vehicles.size(); i++) {
        Vehicle v = vehicles.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < garage.size(); j++) {
            Garage g = garage.get(j);
            if (g.getSpace() == v.getSpace() && g.garageRequest(v.getvehiclesType()) && g.getLimit() > 0) {
                g.addvehicles(v);
                vehicles.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will loop through all the vehicles and try to find a garage that can hold it. If it finds one, it will add the vehicle to the garage and remove it from the list of vehicles. If it doesn't find a garage, it will move on to the next vehicle.

Comment: this really helped me shorter the code. I want to remove the vehicles that were added to the garage when the for loop is done. what I suppose to do with that

Comment: @JosephMartínez After the outer while loop, you could loop through the garage and remove the vehicles that were added.